# 2D array and pointer manipulation for matrix in C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I'm doing a project to create a full matrix suit in C. Which could do most things related to matrix. I've already done it in Python successfully. But I'm trying to do it in C which is actually needed. The way I want to do it is create separate file for separate modules. But I'm really confused about arrays and pointers. I know pointers represent the address of that value.

What I want to do:

1. Make a function module which asks for row n column number n then takes input of the matrix n then returns the array containing the matrix to another empty array so I could just call the function everytime I need a matrix input.

Things I don't understand:

1. How to return an array from a function?
2. or How to return a 2D pointer value from a function? or access it?
3. Anything else wrong with my code?

Errors I'm getting:

1. matrix_in.c:17:9: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
2. matrix.c:9:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
3. matrix.c:16:11: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int (*)[5]' [-Wformat=]

So far my code is as follows:

header /* header.h */

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

#define LIMIT_X 100
#define LIMIT_Y 100
int* matrix_in();

#endif
```

matrix_in
    /* matrix_in.c */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int* matrix_in()
{
    int i,j;
    //int* point;
    static int (*array)[LIMIT_X][LIMIT_Y];
    printf("please enter the elements:\n");
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

matrix
    /* matrix.c */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    int m1[2][2],m2,i,j;
    int (*p1)[5][5];

    p1 = matrix_in();
    //p2 = matrix_in();

    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", *p1);
            p1++;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know what `static int (*array)[LIMIT_X][LIMIT_Y];` means?

Comment: ...and what is the difference with `static int array[LIMIT_X][LIMIT_Y];`?

Comment: I just followed the instruction here [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm)

Comment: Then I believe you mis-read it. Am I correct?

Comment: @PokeDev The link you provided does not implement anything like this.

Comment: `m1` with size of rows and columns pass to `matrix_in`

Comment: This "tutorials" site is pretty bad...

Comment: The first two questions in your list, verbatim, would be *outstanding* to search for on this site Ex: [`[c][array] How to return an array from a function`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D%5Barray%5D+How+to+return+an+array+from+a+function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct is sounds as though you want to call a function that loads a matrix and then return this matrix to be stored in an array elsewhere.

The simple solution to your problem is that you write `int (*p1)[5][5]` which is actually a **3-dimensional array**. It needs to be changed to a 2-D array like `int** p1;` which could then be filled using the code block below.

You have to change the return type in `matrix_in()`. Currently, you are attempting to return and `int*`, which is an 1-D array of ints. This needs to be changed to `int**`.

**Edit:**

So say for example I want a function that loads a 2-D array with a bunch of values and then return this array. I could write it as such:

**Edit 2:**
Due to WhozCraig's comment I realized I needed to make some changes

**Edit 3:**
Changed the code from c++ syntax to c syntax (got confused about the question sorry)

```
int** loadArray(int rows, int cols)
{
    int** array_to_return = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*)); // define one of two dimensions
    int value_to_increment = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        array_to_return[i] = (int*)malloc(cols * sizeof(int)); //define other dimension
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            array_to_return[i][j] = value_to_increment; // fill each index with value
            value_to_increment++;
        }
    }

    return array_to_return;
}
```

This function loads an array with sequential values and then return the array. Now, since we malloc, you will need to `free()` the array at some point so as to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want. can you write the code a little elaborately? Thanks

Comment: Also @PokeDev I would recommend having your matrix_in() function take in two values that are used for the size of the matrix, like my example code. This would allow your matrix to be any size (excluding very very large values).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig for pointing that out. I belive I have fixed the code now

Comment: @bpgeck Or you could [just do **this**](https://ideone.com/6Rw8dP) and avoid the pointer to pointer approach. This is, after all, C.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't even know that was possible. Nifty

Comment: malloc() n calloc() seems new concept to me. I'll need to read the documentation! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: This exactly solved my problem. Thanks for all the answers n helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are represented as a contiguous chunk of memory with a pointer pointing to the 0th element.  Thus, an array generally looks like this:

```
---------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | //A five element array
---------------------
  ^
  |
pointer
to 0th
element
```

Notice that by pointing to the first element in the array, you can access the rest of the elements in the array by simply incrementing the pointer (known as pointer arithmetic).  Thus, if `int *a` points to element 0, we know that we have to increment `a` four times to get to element 4.

2-dimensional arrays are a bit trickier; humans think of a 2-d array like this:

```
---------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  //row 0
---------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  //row 1
---------------------
```

However, computers have no notion of 2 dimensions in memory; a computer just sees (theoretically) one infinitely long row of memory.  Thus, the computer arranges a 2-d array like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 
-----------------------------------------
  ^                   ^
  |                   |
row 0               row 1
begins              begins
here                here
```

This means the computer does some simple arithmetic with the modulus operator to access row 1:

```
a[x][y] = a[ (y * array_width) + x ]
```

So `a[1][2]` becomes `a[1 * 5 + 2] = a[7]`.

This means that to pass a pointer to a 2-d array into a function, **you still only need to pass the pointer to the 0th element in the array**.  You can then access the entire array as usual.

Other answers do a better job of explaining what exactly is wrong with your code - I just want to make sure you understand how arrays work in C :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. but incrementing the pointer should then print the full array? which is not happening? It prints only row 0 n for row 1 it prints just 0 for each element.

Comment: I may have (probably did) oversimplify this - my apologies.  I'm not 100% familiar with the inner workings of gcc (assuming that's the compiler you're using), but it may or may not put the rows of the array next to each other when you declare an array as `int a[x][y]`.  So there might be a gap in the memory locations of the various rows (especially if you declare this array on the stack).  In this case, you'll need a nested for loop to access the entire array.  You can always manually create a 1-d array that emulates a 2-d array as above.

Comment: Regardless, the point about passing the pointer to the 0th element of the array (so for `int a[x][y]`, passing `a` as a pointer to the entire array or passing `a[x]` as a pointer to a particular row) should still stand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take input in matrix you probably just need a 2-D array. Declaration would be this -

```
int array[n][n];  // 2-d array of integers
```

And this  -

```
int (*p1)[5][5];  // p1 is a pointer to a 5 X 5-element array of int
```

Both the things are different.
To return just declare a pointer , allocate memory and then return the pointer. 
And intead of this -

```
static int (*array)[LIMIT_X][LIMIT_Y];
```

you can declare like this -

```
static int array[LIMIT_X][LIMIT_Y];
```

And return `array` -
     `return array;`

This statement -

```
         `scanf("%d",array[i][j]);`
                     ^ & required here
```

Comment: So I should try something like: int matrix_1[n][n]; matrix_1 = matrix_in();

Comment: Well dealing with a 2-d array would be simple.

Comment: tried with: `int p1[n][n]; p1 = matrix_in();` but getting this error `matrix.c:9:5: error: assignment to expression with array type`

Comment: @PokeDev  No you need a double pointer .I was exactly editing my answer for this . Give me a sec.

Comment: I'm confused! can you give me a short example code?

Comment: "you need a double pointer" - no, you don't. You need `int (*p1)[5]`. There is no requirement, nor need, for *any* double-indirection pointers in this code *whatsoever*.

Comment: that was a mistake. but I fixed it. still I'm getting `matrix_in.c:17:9: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` error? also I can't print the values from pointer p1? It prints 1st value n then prints 0 for all other turns.

Comment: @WhozCraig  Why do you think Sir that there is no need of double pointer ? If the function returns a 2-d array then how exactly can you store it into a `int (*p)[5]` ?

Comment: @ameyCU Because [you don't need one](https://ideone.com/6Rw8dP). C is flexible enough to allow significant lenience in how you craft your functions.